# Create Frequency table using R and Term document Matrix

Tags: r, frequency, text-mining, grepl, term-document-matrix

I have created the following dataframe consisting of a few e-mail subject lines.

```
 df <- data.frame(subject=c('Free ! Free! Free ! Clear Cover with New Phone',
                            'Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at 1000. Limited Offer!'))
```

I have created a list of frequent words derived from the above dataframe. I have added these keywords to the dataframe and dummy coded them as 0

```
 most_freq_words <- c('Free', 'New', 'Limited', 'Offer')



Subject                                               Free New Limited Offer                                                    

 'Free Free Free! Clear Cover with New Phone',          0   0     0      0
 'Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at             0   0     0      0
 1000. Limited Offer!'
```

I want to obtain a frequency count of the words in the e mail subject. The output should as follows

```
  Subject                                             Free New Limited Offer                                                    

 'Free Free Free!  Clear Cover with New Phone',         3   1     0      0
 'Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at             0   1     1      2
 1000. Limited Offer!'
```

I have tried the following code

```
for (i in 1:length(most_freq_words)){
df[[most_freq_words[i]]] <- as.numeric(grepl(tolower(most_freq_words[i]), 
tolower(df$subject)))}
```

This however tells if the word is present or not in the sentence. I need the output given above. I request someone to help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option with `tidyverse`.  We use `map` to loop over the 'most_freq_words', get its count from 'subject' column of 'df' with `str_count`, convert to `tibble`, set the names of the column from the 'most_freq_words' and bind the columns with the original dataset 'df'

```
library(tidyverse)
most_freq_words %>% 
      map(~ str_count(df$subject, .x) %>%
                    as_tibble %>% 
                    set_names(.x)) %>% 
      bind_cols(df, .)
#                                                         subject Free New Limited Offer
#1                 Free ! Free! Free ! Clear Cover with New Phone    3   1       0     0
#2 Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at 1000. Limited Offer!    0   1       1     2
```

Answer (score 3):

I handled this task with the tidytext package. First, I added a grouping variable in the data set. Then, I separated words using the `unnest_token()`. I removed all words except the words in `most_freq_words`. Then, I counted how many times each word appeared in each sentence. Finally, I converted a long-format data to a wide-format one. If you still want to have the original sentence, you can add it to the output easily (e.g., adding `cbind(subject = df$subject)` after the `spread()` line)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

df <- data.frame(subject=c('Free ! Free! Free ! Clear Cover with New Phone',
                           'Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at 1000. Limited Offer!'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

most_freq_words <- c('Free', 'New', 'Limited', 'Offer')

mutate(df, group = 1:n()) %>%
unnest_tokens(input = subject, output = word, token = "words", to_lower = FALSE) %>%
filter(word %in% most_freq_words) %>%
count(group, word) %>%
spread(key = word, value = n, fill = 0)

  group  Free Limited   New Offer
  <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  3.00    0     1.00  0   
2     2  0       1.00  1.00  2.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `grepl` with `gregexpr` and then check for the `length` for the `1st` list item. Moreover the `for-loop` should be run over every row of `df` as well. Keeping the `for-loop` intention of OP the modified code will look as:

```
for (i in 1:length(most_freq_words)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[j,most_freq_words[i]] <- ifelse(gregexpr(tolower(most_freq_words[i]),
       tolower(df$subject[j]))[[1]][[1]] >0,
    length(gregexpr(tolower(most_freq_words[i]), tolower(df$subject[j]))[[1]]), 0)
  }
}  


> df
                                                         subject Free New Limited Offer
1                Free ! Free! Free ! Clear Cover with New  Phone    3   1       0     0
2 Offer ! Buy New phone and get earphone at 1000. Limited Offer!    0   1       1     2
```

Comment: This works neatly. Thank you. Can I request an explanation. I ama bit vague as to how it works

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs The value 1st item returned by `gregexpr` tells about if match is  successful or not.  If that value is `-1` then word couldnot found in text. The 2nd one gives vector with match index from text. Hence `length` of that vector will provide you number of occurrence.